# How to save localStorage per story in storybook

Tags: local-storage, storybook, storybook-addon

Is it possible to save something to `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` per story and/or per stories file?

Is there any addon for this, I can't find any

I would expect something like

```js
Default.parameters = {
    sessionStorage: {
        userId: '123'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First, customize your story to use a one-off loader in order to initialize it with some custom local/session storage set up.

```js
// your story definition

export const SomeStory = () => {
  return <SomeComponent />;
};
SomeStory.loaders = [
  () => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("somekey", "somevalue");
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("somekey", "somevalue");
  },
];
```

However, your browser storage (local/session/otherwise) will not be isolated between stories.

You can add a global decorator to reset the storage in between stories to your preview file.

```js
// in preview.tsx

const browserStorageResetDecorator: DecoratorFn = (Story) => {
  window.localStorage.clear();
  window.sessionStorage.clear();
  return <Story />;
};

export const decorators: DecoratorFn[] = [
   browserStorageResetDecorator
];
```

There are other ways to do global decorators, this is just my preference.

See [storybook docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A neat solution I found was to actually store item to local storage before returning your story component.

Comment: I used it too. but it will keep it in the `localStorage` for other stories as well